# How do I stop custom performance counter instance names from being auto converted to lower case

Tags: c#, performance

I have created a multi-instance performance counter and I pass it mixed case instance names but somehow the instance names get converted to lower case when I view them both through code and in perfmon. Does anyone know how to prevent this? Found [this](http://bytes.com/groups/net/609743-performancecounter-multiple-instances) on google, thought it was nice of Luke Zhang to never follow up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I used Reflector to look at the code in System.dll for the PerformanceCounter. In the private Initialize event is this little nugget:

```
this.sharedCounter = new SharedPerformanceCounter(categoryName.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), this.counterName.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), this.instanceName.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), this.instanceLifetime);
```

I think that's why.

Comment: Why? 

(this simple question was not enough for SO  - although it completely makes sense in the context -. Anyway I can write a few more words anytime.)

Comment: Aaaand that's still the case in 2017..... You don't even need to use Reflector/dotPeek, it's in the Reference Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/PerformanceCounter.cs#L537